# How to match until first occurrence of a pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing a file and trying to extract multiple sections in the file. One such section is called 'Report', a single file might contain multiple reports. I wish to extract each of these 'Report' sections from the file using a regex.

**Issue being faced:**

There are multiple sections which end with '-----', how do I stop at the first occurrence of it?

**Current Regex:**

```
-+(\s+)?Report(\s+)?-+\n(.*\n)+\n-{72}
```

This regex, unfortunately, matches all the sections as a single one, whereas I intend to stop at the first occurrence of '----' section ending pattern.

**Sample File:**

**----------- Report -----------**

**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. At hoc in eo M. Si longus, levis; Ita prorsus, inquam; Tu quidem reddes; Ratio quidem vestra sic cogit. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Tum Torquatus: Prorsus, inquit, assentior**

**------------------------------**

Putabam equidem satis, inquit, me dixisse. Dicimus aliquem hilare vivere; Quonam, inquit, modo? Nescio quo modo praetervolavit oratio.

**----------- Report -----------**

**At hoc in eo M. Sed quae tandem ista ratio est? Quoniam, si dis placet, ab Epicuro loqui discimus. Venit ad extremum; Illud non continuo, ut aeque incontentae.**

**------------------------------**

Illi enim inter se dissentiunt. Equidem e Cn. At multis malis affectus. Hoc loco tenere se Triarius non potuit. Haec dicuntur inconstantissime. Efficiens dici potest.

----------- Analysis -----------

At hoc in eo M. Sed quae tandem ista ratio est? Quoniam, si dis placet, ab Epicuro loqui discimus. Venit ad extremum; Illud non continuo, ut aeque incontentae.

*----------------------------*

**Note:**

1. The ending '----' pattern has '-' repeating 72 times
2. There is always a one empty line after '--- Report ---' and before the ending '----'pattern
3. Language being used: Python

Comment: Use `(?s)-+\s*Report\s*-+\n(.*?)\n-{72}` or even `(?sm)^-+\s*Report\s*-+\n(.*?)\n-{72}`

Comment: Thanks so much, @WiktorStribiżew. That worked! 

If you don't mind me asking, what does (?s) do?

Comment: `(?s)` is equal to `re.DOTALL` / `re.S`. `re.compile(r"(?s)a.*?b")` = `re.compile(r"a.*?(?s)b")` = `re.compile(r"a.*?b", re.S)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?s)-+\s*Report\s*-+\n(.*?)\n-{72}
```

Or - since `---Report----`s start at the start of the lines:

```
(?sm)^-+\s*Report\s*-+\n(.*?)\n-{72}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rQDBsA/2)

**Details**:

- `(?s)` - enable DOTALL mode
- `-+` - 1+ hyphens
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `Report` - a substring of literal chars
- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `-+` - 1+ hyphens
- `\n`  - a newline
- `(.*?)` - capturing group 1 matching any 0+ chars but as few as possible up to the first...
- `\n-{72}` - newline followed with 72 hyphens.

Use with `re.findall`.

Comment: Thank you so much, again! This explains perfectly.